# Exception: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am using the [Checkout.com .NET SDK](https://github.com/checkout/checkout-net-library) to integrate my application with their REST API. I have written a proof-of-concept application and everything works fine, but when I try from the actual application I get this error when trying to make API calls:

*"This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request."*

I have cloned the source code, built locally, replaced the nuget reference with my local reference and debugged. The exception is thrown when the WebRequestHandler is created:

```
requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip,
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    UseCookies = false
};
```

The application is using .NET 4.0, Microsoft.Net.HTTP 2.2.29. The only place I can find the code for this to dig further is on [symbolsource.org](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/HttpClient/0.5.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0/Microsoft.Net.Http). In HttpClientHandler there is a volatile bool operationStarted which is only set when Send is called, and throws an exception if you modify the properties when it is set.

```
internal void CheckDisposedOrStarted()
{
    CheckDisposed();
    if (operationStarted)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.net_http_client_operation_started);
    }
}
```

I'm confident that this code is not being called before I hit it the first time, so I can only surmise that **something** else in my application is already making a call with HttpClient and it hasn't been disposed, but I don't know how to find out what without deconstructing the application piece by piece, which is a mammoth task.

I would like to debug the Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 for .NET 4.0 code to try to find the culprit but can't find the source code in complete and downloadable format. I could try to construct it from the code on symbolsource.org but that's not ideal.

Could someone direct me to the source code? Or suggest any other ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've never used this "Checkout.com .NET SDK" so not able to figure out what happened neither.
But since you've already build it locally, it would be helpful, if you can add a log with call stack trace wherever uses the HttpClient. So you would be able to trace the source of unexpected first call.

To get the stack information, you can use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

But please do remove it once you finish the diagnose, it isn't very helpful to leave these kind of log in production code.

---

I'm getting exactly same error, but that's because I intended to reuse the HttpClient when calling Azure API. So it's a different case.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I ended up using RestSharp instead to make the API calls which worked fine.